# Get Email list from Outlook using Python

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

Am trying to get last 1000 emails i received in outlook. But the code only get Email from Main folder not from sub folders.
Please assist

---

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
import dateutil.parser
from datetime import datetime

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                    # any other folder
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
i=1
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Sender','Subject','DateTime'])
Today = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y") # current date and time

while i<1000:
    message=messages[i]
    DT1=message.ReceivedTime
    DT = DT1.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    a=message.SenderEmailAddress
    if "-" in a:
        a=a.split("-",1)[1]
    b=message.subject

    df = df.append({'Sender':a,'Subject':b,'DateTime':DT}, ignore_index=True)
    i+=1
df.to_excel("C:/Users/abc/Downloads/Email.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform a search over multiple folders you need to use the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection.
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

Read more about the `AdvancedSearch` method and find samples in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

The `Restrict` or `Find`/`FindNext` methods of the `Items` class allow getting items according to your conditions from a single folder only.